# Google Maps API on iPhone 7

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am using Google Maps SDK for iOS and it works fine on every iPhone device, except iPhone 7 for some reason. Further more, while using the Xcode simulator (iPhone 7) it works fine but when I upload to app to TestFlight every single iPhone 7 user reports that the map does not work at all (it won't load, like if I am using a wrong API Key).
Any idea of what can the problem be? I have tried switching API Key but of no avail.
[image: this is the image of one of the testers using iPhone 7]

This is the image of one of the testers using iPhone 7
[image]

And this is how I see it in the simulator

Comment: when you run it on device connected to xcode do you see any related messages in the logs?

Comment: @Scriptable , I’ve just noticed that when I connect an iPhone 7 to the Mac and run through Xcode it won’t show me the regular Google Maps SDK message